# Divide 2 numbers in java

Tags: android

i have declared a variable "intermediate"

```
double intermediate;

intermediate = 15/100;
Log.d("xyz", intermediate);
```

And log cat is showing 0.0

I have tried changing intermediate to float, int, long but nthing worked......

Comment: You could use the old Tween Animation API http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html and go if else depending on the Android version code.

Comment: try `intermediate=15.0f/100` . Also, `Log.d("xyz",""+intermediate)` as Log functions need a String

Comment: `intermediate = 15.0 / 100.0` ?

Comment: @fadden that worked.. thnk u

Answer (score 2):

it is showing 0.0 as it is performing the division between two integers.
try this:-

```
double intermediate;

intermediate = (double)15/100;
Log.d("xyz", intermediate);
```

This casts the result in double .